# Iinear regression equation

Tags: r

I have two variables and would like to demonstrate the linear regression between them. For some reason R is not accepting the equation. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance...

```
linregression <- lm(Variable A ~ Variable B)
print(linregression)
summary(linregression)
coefficients(linregression)
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? `Variable A` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: is Variable A and Variable part of a dataset? lm(Variable A ~ Variable B, data=yourdataset)

Comment: Variable A is the name of the column....

Comment: @MLavoie by yourdataset I presume you mean the name of the dataset

Comment: @Gopala how can I post a reproducible sample? apologies I'm very green in this programme...

Comment: Example, here are some of the R things you can post here `df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10);  head(df); str(df); fit <- lm(x ~ y, data = df); 
summary(fit)`

Comment: structure(list(`Variable A` = 58:63, `Variable B` = c(115L, 117L, 
120L, 123L, 126L, 129L)), .Names = c("Variable A", "Variable B"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead...I can't keep posting code chunks in comment section. :)

```
df <- structure(list(VariableA = 58:63, VariableB = c(115L, 117L, 120L, 123L, 126L, 129L)), .Names = c("VariableA", "VariableB" ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
df
  VariableA VariableB
1        58       115
2        59       117
3        60       120
4        61       123
5        62       126
6        63       129

fit <- lm(VariableA ~ VariableB, data = df)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = VariableA ~ VariableB, data = df)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.17442  0.12791  0.08140  0.03488 -0.01163 -0.05814 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 18.05814    1.22618   14.73 0.000124 ***
VariableB    0.34884    0.01007   34.64 4.14e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1206 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9967,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9958 
F-statistic:  1200 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 4.144e-06

print(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = VariableA ~ VariableB, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    VariableB  
    18.0581       0.3488  

coefficients(fit)
(Intercept)   VariableB 
 18.0581395   0.3488372
```

EDIT: I wanted to add this too....IF you insist on having a space in the variable names as you had in the original data, you will need to use backtick to compensate as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(`Variable A` = 58:63, `Variable B` = c(115L, 117L, 120L, 123L, 126L, 129L)), .Names = c("Variable A", "Variable B" ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
fit <- lm(`Variable A` ~ `Variable B`, data = df)
summary(fit)
```

This will work, but not without the proper invocation of variable names with spaces. Not sure this is the best way to work in R, but that is up to the user.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you explain to me what you did? particularly the first part i.e. df <- structure(list(VariableA = 58:63, VariableB = c(115L, 117L, 120L, 123L, 126L, 129L)), .Names = c("VariableA", "VariableB" ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")? Why VariableA = 58:63 and why  VariableB = c(115L, 117L, 120L, 123L, 126L, 129L?

Comment: See my edited answer. Having spaces is possible if you handle them in a special way, which is a real pain and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for this.. OK I got the spaces part.... Can you tell me what you mean by `Variable A` = 58:63, and `Variable B` = c(115L, 117L, 120L, 123L,)?

Comment: That is straight from your comment way above....Trying to create the data set as you specified. 58:63 means simply 58 through 63 in increments of 1.

Comment: Thanks for this.. OK I got the spaces part.... Can you tell me what you mean by `Variable A` = 58:63, and `Variable B` = c(115L, 117L, 120L, 123L,)? I understand its the first 6 elements of both variables. But why 6? And how did you do them? I manually modified to include all the rows and manually inserted all the elements of both vectors. Would it give the same answer?

Comment: oh! indeed! I don't know why it gave 6 rows as my data has 15! That was what came when I typed dput(head(my data).... Do you know why?

Comment: I have another question related to the same data. How can I predict the value of B if A is a particular number ex 100? I put the following equation but no data is coming up... new_data_new<- data_exercise_2[data_exercise_2$VariableA==100,]

Comment: Thanks Ben. indeed it gives structure(list(`Variable A` = 58:72, `Variable B` = c(115L, 117L, 
120L, 123L, 126L, 129L, 132L, 135L, 139L, 142L, 146L, 150L, 154L, 
159L, 164L)), .Names = c("Variable A", "Variable B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))